# javascript object properties is not displaying

Tags: javascript

I have below javascript function-

```
function ResponseVal()
{
    this.value1;
    this.value2;
} 


var Response = new ResponseVal();
```

I tried and execute above code in chrome consolebar.I could not understand why newly created object "Response" does not show property value1 and value2. Can anyone help me to understand it what is happening  and why properties are not displaying.

Comment: You never create the properties `value1` or `value2`. All you do is trying to *read* them, which will fail (because they don't exist) and `undefined` will be returned. If you assign a value to them, then they will be created. Simpler example: `var obj = {}; obj.foo; obj.bar = 42; console.log(obj);`.

Comment: Thanks for response.But if declaring the property is not sufficient then what would be the way to creating properties in js without initializing it.

Comment: You can't declare properties like you declare variables (i.e. `var foo;`). Properties are only created if you assign a value to them. That value could be `null` or `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring a property without setting it essentially does nothing. While it won't result in an error, some interpreters will throw a warning—as will strict mode, I believe.

JavaScript doesn't make this immediately obvious. For example, if you do this:

```
function Hello() { 
    this.value1;
}

var h = new Hello;
alert(h.value1);
```

The alert will read `undefined`. However, the property `value1` was never actually accessed—it doesn't exist at all because you did not provide a value for it.

Rather than throwing an error, JavaScript returns `undefined` any time you try to access a property that doesn't exist. So you will get the same result if you write, say:

```
alert(h.property_that_doesnt_exist);   //alerts 'undefined'
```

Iterating through the properties of `h` shows clearly that the property `value1` does not exist:

```
for (var key in h) {
    alert(key + ' = ' + h[key]);
}
```

This alerts nothing, because no properties will be found. However, if you set the property to the JS primitive `undefined`, the property WILL exist:

```
function Hello() { 
    this.value1 = undefined;
}

var h = new Hello;

for (var key in h) {
    alert(key + ' = ' + h[key]);  //alerts 'undefined'
}
```

You can run the above code here: http://jsfiddle.net/Acdmn/

---

But there's no good reason to set a property/variable to `undefined`. To create a property with an "empty" value, JavaScript programmers typically use `null`:

```
function Hello() { 
    this.value1 = null;
}
```

This makes it clear that the property was created intentionally, but you're not ready to give it a meaningful value yet.

---

Lastly, note that property definitions work differently from "normal" (private) variables explicitly set with `var` (even though these are also properties, in this case of the `window` object). If you write:

```
var foo;
alert(foo);
alert(some_undefined_variable_name);
```

The first alert will say `undefined`. The variable `foo` *was* created, does exist, and contains the primitive value `undefined` (even though you didn't set it explicitly). The second alert, however, will throw a reference error:

```
ReferenceError: some_undefined_variable_name is not defined
```

So JavaScript is unforgiving about using undefined variables, but it doesn't care if you try to use an undefined property.

Answer (score 4):

You should set the values to something. All you've done is try to read them in the constructor.

```
function ResponseVal()
{
    this.value1 = "";
    this.value2 = "";
} 


var Response = new ResponseVal();
```

Answer (score 0):

They are still undefined.  They only exist once defined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign values to value1 and value2, 'null' at least.